# Fillna() in Pandas Dataframe python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

There is a data of titanic_dataset:
like below here:
[Dataframe before fillna() with NaN values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk8jr.png)

```
import pandas as pd
titanic_excel=pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\mithi\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\pyps\\Domain-wise Task 2\\titanic_excel.xlsx")

titanic_excel.fillna('') # I tried titanic_excel.fillna() also
#print(titanic_excel.dtypes)
titanic_excel
titanic_excel.head()
```

[What I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMYY3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `fillna()` does not modify the original dataframe. You  need to assign it back to the original `df`.

```
titanic_excel = titanic_excel.fillna('')
print(titanic_excel)
```